# Symfony redirect with response

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, symfony-2.3

i would like to know is there anyway to return from controller an 500 exceptional error. i need to return with response, code and redirection.Please help me out of it

Comment: No.  There is not.  By definition, redirects have a status code of 3xx.  Basic http stuff.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return "500 Internal Server Error" just throw an exception, for example:

```
throw new \Exception();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don`t have idea for what you can need that, but when you return $this->render and path that does not exist , symfony returns 500.

Comment: But i am using angular js i can't use $this->render @Mat.eo